# Button stretch when gradient applied

Tags: ios, swift, button, gradient

First I set constraints to a button in storyboard. Then, I edited it in code to make it look good.
When I apply my gradient function to a button it becomes bigger than before. How do you fix that?

```
extension UIView {
    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
        self.applyGradient(colours, locations: nil)
    }

    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> Void {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.CGColor }
        gradient.locations = locations
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

I just applied it on one button and..
[Here is the pic...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1eak.png)

Now after that it looks like this...The gradient bound did nothing [It goes way outside frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJMEt.png) PLZPLZPLZ try to help me :) I appreciate ur help so far

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.layer.masksToBounds = true` to the function. This will mean that the sublayer you added won't draw outside of the original frame of the button

EDIT:
If you want the shadow as well you'll need to set `self.layer.masksToBounds` to false, since it will clip the shadow too.

Try `gradient.frame = self.layer.bounds` instead maybe?

Comment: It says Value of type CALAyer has no member clipsToBounds...what to I do

Comment: Actually the gradient is there but the shadow that i added is gone after .MaskstoBounds... I did                                                                                              
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.9  button.layer.shadowRadius=1.0 buttonLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,3)                          The whole shadow disappeared, presumably because it did not fit in the original frame...so how do i keep that

Comment: Basically it  worked to limit size...but The button shadow disappeared....how do u fix that

Comment: Without the masksToBOunds it goes way outside back to normal, if u follow the image link above, but there is shadow..Plz help :) I appreciate it